# Eclipse - Bundle GWT web content into Enterprise Application Project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, ear

I created an "Enterprise Application Project" in eclipse (including an ejb and web module). Now I want to bundle a GWT "Web Application Project" into my EAR-file. So I created the project and included it in my enterprise application project.

[image]

[image] [image]

If I export the EAR file and look into the generated JAR file of the GWT project, it only contains the classes and not the HTML files in the "war" (This is the folder GWT projects contain der web elements like HTML, JS) folder. I also tried to rename the "war" folder to WebContent, but it is still not contained in the EAR.

Is there any way to get this folder bundled in?

**Edit:** @philfr49: I only have these facets:

[image]

Comment: Did you compile the GWT project?

Comment: @El Hoss: Yes I did, but the host page in the war folder was present before anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the GWT project facet:
[image]

With these parameters:
[image]

So your GWT project will be deployed as a war (instead of jar) with all html and generated javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't have this facet in my GWT project (see also my updated question)